# Increase the speed of saving data to sql database using hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

There are 20000-30000 records that I have to save it into MySQL using Hibernate. So that Hibernate will generate 20000-30000 insert queries too. It takes me 1-2 minutes to make everything done, and it will cause a 504 request time-out to my website.

Firstly, I did it like this:

```
for (some loop elements) {
    Object foo = new Object();
    // do some foo get/set to fulfill the fields.
    objectService.save(foo);
}
```

That's a lot of time. Then I tried save a list into db, like:

```
List<Object> objs = new ArrayList<>();
for (some loop elements) {
    Object foo = new Object();
    // do some foo get/set to fulfill the fields.
    objs.add(foo);
}
objectService.saveAll(objs);
```

Something like that.

With the saving individual object/record into db, it takes a longer time than saving a list. But saving a list still caught the time-out. So the question is: Is there any solution to speed up the process, less query than my solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes you can use batch

Comment: Yes, you can generate de record ID yourselfe, then set the id provider to the new current value OR you can create an stored procedure to save your record OR you can Override `.saveAll(...)` (because it's just an `foreach::save(...)`) OR you can bypass Hibernate and make your save through an parametrized SQL request.

Comment: @YCF_L i'm googling for it, thank you!

Comment: you can use the method saveAll  and set the property spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size  to bulk inserts.

Comment: Enable batch processing and flush/clear each x records (for x find the sweetspot but for example 100). See https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-do-batch-processing-with-jpa-and-hibernate/